# Can some one summarize briefly what each line is doing here please?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just got this RoR app working, and just want some clarification to what exactly went on behind the scenes, briefly so I can look into each step:

```
    Clone the git repo

 git clone git://github.com/railsdog/spree.git spree
 cd spree
Install the gem dependencies

 bundle install
Create a sanbox rails application for testing purposes

 rails new sandbox -m sample/sandbox_template.rb
 cd sandbox
Generate the necessary Spree files

 rails g spree:install
Bootstrap the database (run the migrations, create seed data, optionally load sample data.)

 rake db:migrate db:seed db:sample
Start the server

 rails server
```

I know what the 1st line is doing, git clone ...

---

But does bundle install download all the dependancies from what file?
Where does the call to rails g spree:install look to generate the files?

I know rake is like 'make', but is it really compiling new code?
Or does rake just run the migration scripts etc. i.e. no compiling going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go through it step-by-step:

```
git clone git://github.com/railsdog/spree.git spree
```

This checks out the latest code from git to the directory spree

```
bundle install
```

This parses the Gemfile in your directory and installs the dependencies for your application accordingly.

```
rails new sandbox -m sample/sandbox_template.rb
```

This creates a new rails project from a rails-template, this template instructs rails to generate the application with certain pre-defined parameters.

```
rails g spree:install
```

A generator that comes with spree that has instructions on how to make your spree application ready for use.

```
rake db:migrate db:seed db:sample
```

Migration the database migrations and feel the application with seed and demo-date.

Rake might compile certain things, if the sqlite gem needs to be installed for instance rake will make sure you compile it correctly. It differs per situation.

Comment: thanks, so where is the spree:install instructions? what file?

Comment: You don't _have_ to know what it does, it just installs stuff for you automatically. If you want to know what the code behind it is you can look in the "spree/lib/generators" folders